# How to create a regular expression in Google Forms that checks for character length and capitalization

Tags: regex, character, google-forms

I am trying to create a regular expression in Google Forms for a quiz for middle-schoolers. I would like for the quiz to display an error code if students do not include any capital letters in their response. I would also like for the form to enforce a minimum character limit (250). I have tried using:

```
/^.{250,}$/
```

But Google Forms throws an error and reverts to previous version of the form whenever I put in curly braces. Here's what I have so far to check for capitalization:

```
[A-Z]*[.]\s[A-Z]
```

How do I add onto this to get it to also check for character length? As you can probably tell, I'm a novice. A teacher, not a programmer. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You cannot impose these two conditions in Google Forms RE2 regex as it does not support lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor is correct regarding the capabilities to check the entire response for capitalization *and* length.  If you simplified the requirement to deal with answers that *start* with a capital letter (which is a specialization of your initial requirement), you could use this regex:   `^[A-Z].{249,}`